# Set up Prometheus with docker-compose to get metrics of existing Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have prometheus config that works on my cluster deployed by terraform. Now, I would like to setup Prometheus using the same prometheus.yml locally (outside terraform). I created a new project to set up Promethese using docker-compose and use the same prometheus.yml file but when I go to prometheus site, it seems like the metrics for kubernetes is not available, such as these metrics about kubernetes containers:
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total
container_cpu_load_average_10s
container_memory_usage_bytes
container_memory_rss

Could you please let me know what I am missing in my project to make this work?

This is `prometheus.yml`

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'prometheus'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9090']
- job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['10.36.1.10']
    - targets: ['10.36.2.6']
    - targets: ['10.36.1.12']
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: https://10.36.1.10:6443
    role: node
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
  - api_server: https://10.36.2.6:6443
    role: node
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
  - api_server: https://10.36.1.12:6443
    role: node
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
  - role: pod
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
    target_label: __address__
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_component]
    action: replace
    target_label: job
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

And, this is `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.21.0
    ports:
      - 9000:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus-data:/prometheus
    command: --web.enable-lifecycle  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:$GRAFANA_VERSION
    environment:
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER: $GRAFANA_ADMIN_USER
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD: $GRAFANA_ADMIN_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:

volumes:
  prometheus-data:
  grafana-storage:
```

[image: ipK8s]

[image: node_exporter]

Answer (score 1):

You are running the **Prometheus** at the local and server level both.

server one working fine and getting the metrics of Kubernetes containers as it's on kubernetes.

while docker-compose one not working due to you are running it locally on docker not on kubernetes cluster.

it's the issue of the **Target**  your Prometheus is not getting the metrics of your **Kubernetes** cluster.

for example, you are running the **Prometheus** locally but want to monitor the external **Kubernetes** cluster you have to expose your **Kube-state-metrics** service using **IP**.

in that case your Prometheus config will have job like

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['address'] //address of the k8s service IP
```

in your case you have to do something like

```
kubernetes_sd_configs:
- api_server: https://<ip>:6443
  role: node
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
```

this will fetch the metrics of kubernetes cluster and you can see data locally.

you can read this nice gist : https://gist.github.com/sacreman/b61266d2ec52cf3a1af7c278d9d93450

Comment: Thank you so much @Harsh Manvar I will try this

Comment: Hello @Harsh Manvar I changed the config as suggested, I check the IP address of k8s service with command `kubectl get pod -o wide` and this is what I get [k8sIP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA6VZ.png), so I added under `scrape_configs`:
```
- job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['10.36.1.10']
    - targets: ['10.36.2.6']
    - targets: ['10.36.1.12']
```
and

Comment: And also under `kubernetes_sd_configs`:
```
- api_server: https://10.36.1.10:6443
    role: node
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
  - api_server: https://10.36.2.6:6443
    role: node
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
  - api_server: https://10.36.1.12:6443
    role: node
    bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
```

Comment: I update the yml in the post so it's more clear

Comment: I feel like its not correct because when I check Prometheus, I still dont see these container metrics

Comment: je veux voir ces metrics:
[node_exporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxuiX.png)

Comment: the node_exporter metrics can be collected, querying each node, usually on port 9142. These have nothing to do with the Kubernetes API. You could use a scrape_config. Or a kubernetes_sd_discovery, if there is a Service pointing to your node_exporters. If you're not familiar with Prometheus & Kubernetes (there's a few stuff to collect, ...), it might be easier to go with some prometheus-operator deployment in Kubernetes, then federating those metrics into your docker-compose based Prometheus deployment.

Comment: Thank you @SYN I would like to try this, could you please recommend me the good link to do this method?

Comment: @SYN should I follow this?
https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator

Comment: Sure, that's one way to go about it. Looking at the gist suggested above, there's quite a lot of stuff missing (cadvisor metrics, kube-state-metrics, kubelet metrics, ...). Better start from a blank slate. Besides, the Prometheus operator is meant for this. I'm not a fan, but it's a pretty good fit until you'ld have some better understanding on how that whole ecosystem works

Comment: Yes there is lots of stuff missing in gist but just shared it to share the details how it cloud be done.

Comment: @Harsh Manvar sorry I haven't had time to try this config on my Prometheus local on docker-compose yet as I have Prometheus deployed by Terraform/Helm that seems to work for Kubernetes but some issue with configMap (as you replied in another thread, thank you). I have upvoted your reply.